# WebAPI SSL and non-ssl controller at IIS

Tags: asp.net, client-certificates

I'm facing non-trivial problem with webapi.

I'll describe here shortly what the problem is, later I'll present two approaches that are potentially "to discuss", and at the end I'll tell you what my thoughts are.

---

### THE PROBLEM:

What I'm facing is such a scenario that I've a RESTFul webapi's application that has two controllers. Let's say `"MutualAuthController"` and `"NonAuthController"`. I would like to host it at IIS in such a manner that `MutualAuthController` will be mutually secured (SSL with client certs) while the `NonAuthController` is not secured at all. So let's say I can access: somehost/MutualAuth (over HTTPS) and somehost/NonAuth (over HTTP)

---

### FIRST APPROACH:

I do not have any problems with setting correct security. I have a problem with "unsecuring" the second controller. 
Once I've ticked "Require SSL" and "Require Cert" in IIS' SSL Configuration, network traffic is trivial: clientSayHello to server, server responds with server hello and REQUIRE CLIENT CERTIFICATE. Such a client sends response with client certificate. Now it's obvious that the second controller acts the same way which is not the case. I want to make it work on basic http endpoint. So once I've spent few hours of research I've gave up and went other way because I simply do not know how to "unsecure" only a part of an SSL secured web application.

---

### SECOND APPROACH:

The other approach was to configure IIS in this way that it does not require SSL but accepts client certificates. Hence, `MutualAuthController` could have some POSTMethod which requires HTTPS -> just like it is described by Mike here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api 
, while the `NonAuthController` will not have such an attribute. In such an attribute I could then call `Request.GetClientCertificate()` and make my validations. Seems easy right?

---

### THOUGHTS:

Everything is so obvious and fine beside one crucial fact. Client is not sending certificate at all because transport layer did not required it. The SSL Handshake in this case is set by IIS and it's underlaying stack.

Has anyone faced similar problems? Or maybe is there any chance to pass client certificate even if server (IIS) didn't wanted it?

---

Added after few tens of minutes...

BTW: I've just found something nasty in my very very tired mind. Going with first approach. 
Could it work that I would create some `BypassIISHttpsAttribute` that will override `OnAuthorization` method and let it pass if it is HTTP?
For example in this way:

```
public class BypassIISHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thank You very much for reading all content and maybe for some replies? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 7 or above, you can create two rewrite rules: one for the secure controller and one for the other.  Use [this](http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/url-rewrite-for-iis7-http-to-https-redirection) link to go from http to https.  Then reverse it for the other controller.  You will need to allow unsecure traffic so don't require SSL.  Just rewrite the URLs to the correct security method based on a regular expression.

Comment: Hi Josh. Unfortunately I'm using the iis6 :|

Comment: Nevertheless it does not resolve my problem. I don't have an issue with accessing http or https explicitly. The problem is that one controller has to be mutual secured - accomplished via IIS config: "Require SSL, Certificate: Require", while the second controller has to bypass this requirement.

Comment: Actually it does.  By rewriting at the IIS level, no request to http://securecontroller will ever occur because the server will rewrite over SSL.  But you are using IIS 6 so you'll have to go about this in a different manner.

Comment: So the solution is to rewrite unsecured controller from https to http ?

Comment: (keep in mind that I've to have both "require SSL" and "Certificate: Require" ticks set) at IIS